# WSO2 Identity Server rest api documentation

Tags: rest, api, wso2

I have been looking at the SOAP api calls that are supported by the identity server RemoteUserStoreManager layer, but have been told that I need to use the REST end points that were implimented in version 5.3.
I though that equivalent call points were being created, but I have been unable to find any documentation for the REST endpoints.

Speficically I want to be able to perform these discrete functions as supported by the SOAP end points:

```
addUser
deleteUser
addUserClaimValue
getUserClaimValue
setUserClaimValue
deleteUserClaimValue
isExistingUser
updateCredentialsByAdmin
authenticate
```

It may be that I am missing the point and that the rest end points have been set up differently so should be used in a different way, but in either case I cannot find any documentation/examples showing all the REST end points available